# when I try to display records in firestore using my flutter ap it gives a error called ' EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY'

Tags: flutter, exception, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

Here is the error I got

> ╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY
> ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty, state:
> _StreamBuilderBaseState<User, AsyncSnapshot>#0ddea):
> The getter 'department' was called on null.
> Receiver: null Tried calling: department
> The relevant error-causing widget was:
> StreamBuilder

here is the codes. I am going to develop a online noticebord. those codes worked properly before the new dart update.After I gave the update It gives above mentioned error.Please give me a way to fix it

**approvenotice.dart**

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

 return StreamProvider<List<Notice>>.value(
  value: NoticeService().notices, 
  child: Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    elevation: 0.0,
   title: Text('Aprove Notices',
   style: TextStyle(
     fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
     fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
     color: Colors.white,
   ),
   ),
   backgroundColor: Colors.blue[800],
   actions: <Widget>[
     IconButton(
       icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.white,), 
       onPressed: (){}
       ),
       
   ], 
  ),
  

body:UnApprovedNotices() ,
```

**UnapproveNotices.dart**

```
 class UnApprovedNotices extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _UnApprovedNoticesState createState() => _UnApprovedNoticesState();
 }

 class _UnApprovedNoticesState extends State<UnApprovedNotices> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final notices = Provider.of<List<Notice>>(context) ?? [];

    
    return StreamBuilder<List<Notice>>(
  stream: NoticeService().notices,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      
      return GridView.builder (
        
      itemCount: notices.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 1),
      // ignore: missing_return
      itemBuilder: (context,index){
          return SingleNotice(
          notice:notices[index]

        );
      }
     }
      
      
    );
  }else{
    return(Text('No List'));
  }
    }
```

Allthough there is records in firestore it displays 'No List' with giving above mentioned error.

Comment: You need to share code part having `StreamBuilder<User>`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by `department` property was called on null, which means,
you are tried to call something like `user.department`, unfortunately `user` is null.

I assume, you are causing trouble because you didn't handle `AsyncSnapshot` correctly.

In order to implement snapshot data properly, you have handle every state which `AsyncSnapshot` had.

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
  // Return Widget to display error
  // snapshot.error will be not nil.
  return ErrorWidget(snapshot.error);
} else {
   if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
       // snapshot is waiting for data
       // Generally we could use this to show `CircularProgressIndicator`
       return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
   } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
      // Snapshot will contains particular data.
      // get this value by snapshot.data 
      return DataWidget(snapshot.data);
   }
}
```

Note: Code not Tested. Hope this helps for general implementation. If need more control of `ConnectionState`, make switch statement.

Read more about at flutter documentation: [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) class.